# How many steps of crystals rotation typical LCD display has for each pixel?

Tags: lcd

I just got a comprehensive response for brightness + contrast for LCD TVs in [Brightness / contrast controls: what they do on LCD displays?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/694821/brightness-contrast-controls-what-they-do-on-lcd-displays).

And realized that when RGB data is transmitted to LCD display, display may add an offset to make image brighter. Therefore I wonder if some of dynamic range of 256 shades of 24 bit RGB is lost in the process. It is lost if number of steps each crystal can make is 256, but can be preserved if that number is times higher. Which is it?

Comment: That depends on panel bit depth plus how the brightness is controlled. You can't even assume that for an 8-bit panel the white of 255,255,255 sent from PC to display controller will get send directly to panel as 255,255,255 as you have to do colour balance etc operations. And the panel might be 6-bit. With dithering. And the brightness setting may be a combination of controlling the backlight and pixel data. Panels exist from 6 to 10 bits, maybe up to 12 bits already.